# What materials or situations require plugs/anchors for screws?

Tags: wood, screws, particle-board

## Context :

I have an [Ikea's Gerton](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/gerton-tabletop-beech-50106773/) tabletop (solid beech, 3 cm thick) and two [Ikea's Alex drawers blocks](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/alex-drawer-unit-white-00473546/) as feet (Ikea's Alex, panes are 1.6 cm thick).
I'd like to fix heavy stuff on the opposite edge (setup of several monitors and an heavy stand for it at the very opposed end of the tabletop).
Since the drawers aren't as deep as the tabletop is large, and since there's nothing below the opposite edge (gap of around 20cm), I'd like to prevent the tabletop with fixed equipment from tipping over (even if I'm unsure it would happen).

I'd like to fasten and secure it.

## The solution I'm considering :

Beside the addition of feet at the two opposite corners, I'm considering a screws/brackets based solution.
I'll probably use wooden dowel pins in order to prevent constraints for both horizontal axis on screws. And add fixing brackets and screws for other axis (vertical constraints).
So the constraints I'd like to possibly handle through screws are mostly perpendicular to the screws length axis on the drawers blocks (particleboard), and parallel to the screws length axis for screws under the tabletop (solid wood).

## My question :

I've chosen screws and [fixing brackets](https://media.monmagasingeneral.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/F/FF79F0AB4O-equerre-de-chaise-bouts-ronds-pvm-dimens.jpg) but I don't know if I should use [plugs/anchors](https://bricoleurpro.ouest-france.fr/images/dossiers/historique/chevilles-classiques-074432.jpg) for screws.

Before putting screws,should I (and why should I) use plugs/anchors for wood (length axis constraints), particleboard (constraints perpendicular to the screw length axis), both or neither?

Comment: The terminologies confuse me, what is a square, and how the plug looks like? Please indicate your origin, or provide photos to clarify.

Comment: The differences in depth aren't that much (50mm according to your links).  That's not enough to make a difference.  Anyway, since it's a monitor clamp, what matters isn't the edge, but the center of gravity of the monitors.

Comment: @r13 I apologize, English isn't my first language and several different words may be identical in my mother tongue (French).
I proceeded as you requested, changed "squares" for "fixing brackets" and "plugs" for "anchors" after verification. I hope it's clearer that way.
I also added links to pictures in order to make it even clearer in case I still used the wrong words.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I may be wrong but after checking, the depth difference is more precisely 17cm (75cm - 58cm). I agree on the center of gravity subject. But since  since the blocks aren't fixed, it can slip if something leans on it. I'd like to secure it also for that reason. Plus, I tried to do some calculus on the required torque to make it tip over (I may be wrong about that tho) and it's not that high so I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you fastening the tabletop to the wall? What is the wall made of - concrete, brick, drywall?

Comment: @r13 No, I am not. I'm mostly wondering if screwing in wood or particleboard may require such kind of anchors. It may sound as a silly question but I'm really unsure about it.

Comment: No, if screw into wood or particleboard the plug is not required, because the threads of the screw need to bite/bind the wood so it can prevent from pulling out, which will occur if a plug is used. After drilling a pilot hole, you shall apply wood glue, then twist the screw in. I sometimes use Teflon (white) tape instead of glue for ease of back out the screw for maintainance.